# flutter - chat's input box keyboard pushing message-list upwards

Tags: flutter

I have a fairly simple flutter app. It has a chat feature.
However, I have a problem with the chat feature.
It's made up of a widget does Scaffold and in it SingleChildScrollView - which has a message-list (container) and input-area (container). Code is attached.

Problem is: if I click on the input box, the keyboard opens and it pushes the message-list.
Pushing the message-list is an acceptable thing if you are already at the bottom of the message-list.
However, if the user scrolled up and saw some old messages, I don't want the message-list widget to be pushed up.
Also, I don't want the message-list to be pushed up if I have only a handful of messages (because that just makes the messages disappear when keyboard opens, and then I need to go and scroll to the messages that have been pushed [user is left with 0 visible messages until they scroll]).

I tried different approaches - like

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

But nothing seems to work for me, and this seems like it should be a straightforward behavior (for example, whatsapp act like the desired behavior).
My only option I fear is to listen to keyboard opening event, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Here's my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.1),
            buildMessageList(), // container
            buildInputArea(context), // container
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );


  Widget buildInputArea(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.1,
      width: width,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildChatInput(),
          buildSendButton(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildMessageList() {
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.8,
      width: width,
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return buildSingleMessage(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildMessageList(),
            buildInputArea(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildInputArea(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.send),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildMessageList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 50,
        controller: _controller,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 20,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that you are using fixed sizes for all widgets. In this case it is better to use `Expanded` for the `ListView` and removing the `SingleChildScrollView`. That way the whole `Column` won't scroll, but only the `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Stack:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: height * 0.1),
                buildMessageList(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: buildInputArea(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `false` in your `Scaffold` should work.

You can use `NotificationListener` to listen to scroll notifications to detect that user is at the bottom of the message-list. If you are at the bottom you can then set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `true`.

Something like this should work

```dart
final resizeToAvoidBottomInset = true;

_onScrollNotification (BuildContext context, ScrollNotification scrollNotification) {
  if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
    // detect scroll position here
    // and set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false if needed
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        return _onScrollNotification(context, scrollNotification);
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildMessageList(), // container
            buildInputArea(context), // container
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is technically already answered, and the answer is almost correct. However, I have found a better solution to this. Previously the author mentions that he wants to have a similar experience to WhatsApp. By using the previous solution, the listview would not be able to scrolldown to maxExtent when the sent button is pressed. To fix this I implemented Flex instead of Expanded, and use a singlechildscrollview for the input area

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  TextEditingController _textcontroller=TextEditingController();
  List<String> messages=[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: messages.length,
            controller: _controller,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print("From listviewbuilder: ${messages[index]}");
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 20,
                    child: Text(messages[index])
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(controller: _textcontroller),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                _controller.animateTo(
                  _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
                  //scroll the listview to the very bottom everytime the user inputs a message
                  curve: Curves.easeOut,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                );
              });
              setState(() {
                messages.add(_textcontroller.text);
              });

              print(messages);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.send),
          ),
        ],
    ),
      ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

It's better to use flex because expanded as the documentation says, expands over available space, whereas flex would resize to the appropriate proportion. This way if you are going for the "WhatsApp experience" in which the listview scrolls down once you sent a message. The listview would resize when the keyboard pops up and you will get to the bottom, instead of it not going fully to the bottom.